# Updated - Declare a value and set with different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am not sure if this is possible the way I am going about this problem, but if you have an solution or alternative way to overcome this, it would be greatly appreciated.

To explain, I have a list of tracking numbers and I want to declare the "ShipDate" as the "AddedDate" and after declare the "DueDeliveryDate"  as "ShipDate"+days depending what day it was shipped.

The issue here is it will update all the tracking numbers with the same date which is declared first for both "ShipDate" and "DueDeliveryDate".

See SQL code:

```
begin tran
Declare @ShipDate varchar(max) = (Select cast(AddedDate as date) from
                                    (select distinct a.TrackingNumber, b.AddedDate 
                                     from ConTransaction a
                                     inner join Consignment b 
                                     on a.TrackingNumber = b.TrackingNumber
                                     where a.TrackingNumber in 
                                                          (
                                                          Select TrackingNumber                                                                    
                                                          from Consignment  C WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                                          Where ShipDate > DateAdd(d, 7, Convert(smalldatetime,Convert(Varchar(10),getdate(),126)))
                                                          AND [Status] = 0                                                     
                                                          ))part01)

Declare @DueDeliveryDate datetime 

Begin

if datename(weekday,@ShipDate)  = 'Friday' 
   set @DueDeliveryDate = dateadd(day,3,@ShipDate)
if datename(weekday,@ShipDate)  = 'Saturday' 
   set @DueDeliveryDate = dateadd(day,2,@ShipDate)
else
   set @DueDeliveryDate = dateadd(day,1,@ShipDate)


Update CN
Set ShipDate = @ShipDate
,DueDeliveryDate = @DueDeliveryDate
,UpdatedBy = 'IT ADMIN'
-- Select *    
FROM dbo.Consignment CN
Where cn.TrackingNumber in (
          select distinct a.TrackingNumber 
          from ConTransaction a
          inner join Consignment b 
          on a.TrackingNumber = b.TrackingNumber
          where a.TrackingNumber in (
                       Select TrackingNumber      
                       from Consignment  C WITH (NOLOCK) 
                       Where ShipDate > DateAdd(d, 7,Convert(smalldatetime,Convert(Varchar(10),getdate(),126))) 
                       and [Status] = 0                                                     
                       and TrackingNumber in ( '65560460605' , '50454646064')
                                            ))
end


--rollback tran
```

Here is a snippet of the table:

```
TrackingNumber | ShipDate            | UpdatedBy | AddedDate           | Status | DueDeliveryDate
65560460605    | 2018-08-10 00:00:00 | NULL      | 2018-08-06 00:00:00 | 0      | 2018-09-09 00:00:00
50454646064    | 2018-08-12 00:00:00 | NULL      | 2018-08-10 00:00:00 | 0      | 2018-09-10 00:00:00
```

Comment: The reason is because you're using a single value for @DueDeliveryDate and applying it in one single set operation (ie- the UPDATE).  Can you post some sample data?  The logic should be done within the UPDATE statement for it to work on a record by record basis.

Comment: Well you calculate the values of the variables once and then update the table with this values. No wonder all records affected share the same values. Somehow the dates should be relative to a value stored in the table. But unfortunately your question doesn't explain which value that should be. Try to edit the question and explain that.

Comment: So the "cumbersome" part where you determine the `@ShipDate` is probably the key to understanding this.  At present you have three answers, but they are all pretty much useless, as all they do is rewrite your bad logic into other forms of the SAME bad logic.  We need to see how you calculate "AddedDate" as "ShipDate" as this will probably be the crux of the problem.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I have solved it I will update the the question with the answer. I was making it more difficult than it needed to be. Thanks for all your help. Once you see the script it will be a lot clear what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See solution below:

```
UPDATE a
SET ShipDate = a.AddedDate             
,DueDeliveryDate = CASE
                  WHEN datename(weekday,a.AddedDate)  = 'Friday' THEN 
                  dateadd(day,3,a.AddedDate)
                  WHEN datename(weekday,a.AddedDate)  = 'Saturday' THEN 
                   dateadd(day,3,a.AddedDate) 
                  ELSE dateadd(day,1,a.AddedDate) 
                  END
,UpdatedBy = 'IT ADMIN'
,UpdatedDate = getdate()
-- Select *    
FROM dbo.Consignment a
Where 
TrackingNumber in 
(
SELECT DISTINCT a.TrackingNumber 
FROM ConTransaction a
INNER JOIN Consignment b 
ON a.TrackingNumber = b.TrackingNumber
WHERE a.TrackingNumber in (SELECT TrackingNumber  
                                FROM Consignment  C WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                WHERE ShipDate > DateAdd(d, 7, 
Convert(smalldatetime,Convert(Varchar(10),getdate(),126)))
                                AND [Status] = 0
                                AND TrackingNumber IN
                                         ( 65560460605,
                                           50454646064 )
                            )
)
```

***So I update the "ShipDate" with the "AddedDate" then depending on the day I updated the "DueDeliveryDate" using the "AddedDate" ***

If any can suggest a different title it make this question stand out a bit better feel free to let me know and I will update it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
Begin

Update CN
Set ShipDate = @ShipDate
,DueDeliveryDate = case 
   when datename(weekday,@ShipDate)  = 'Friday' 
         then dateadd(day,3,@ShipDate)
   when datename(weekday,@ShipDate)  = 'Saturday' 
        then dateadd(day,2,@ShipDate)
   else dateadd(day,1,@ShipDate) end
,UpdatedBy = 'IT ADMIN'
,UpdatedDate = getdate()
-- Select *    
FROM dbo.Consignment CN
Where cn.TrackingNumber in ( **List of tracking number** )
```

Comment: Thanks Cetin, you pointed me in the right direction I will post the correct solution and you can see what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it with `case` expression :

```
set @DueDeliveryDate = dateadd(day, (case datename(weekday,@ShipDate)
                                          when 'Friday' then 3
                                          when 'Saturday' then 2
                                          else 1 
                                     end), @ShipDate
                              )

update cm
     set ShipDate = @ShipDate,
         DueDeliveryDate = @DueDeliveryDate,
         UpdatedBy = 'IT ADMIN',
         UpdatedDate = getdate()  
from dbo.Consignment cn
where cn.TrackingNumber in ( **List of tracking number** );
```